C#.Net IBM MQ Multi threaded application Connection Issue
When I connect to IBM MQ QueueManager using multi-threading, it does not connect all of the requests to MQ. Few connect and few fail. If I use thread count as 1 then all the request are connected. When I increase thread count to 2 or 3 then few will success and few will fail.
Fail with 2009 MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN
Iam using below code in C#.

public void InwardAMLRequestSendProcess()
        {
            try
            {
                string Error = string.Empty;
                string ErrorCode = string.Empty;
                DAL_InwardAMLProcess objDAL_AMLDetails = new DAL_InwardAMLProcess();
                List<AMLRequestDetails> lstAMLRequestDetails = new List<AMLRequestDetails>();                

                lstAMLRequestDetails = objDAL_AMLDetails.GetInwardPendingAMLRequestDetailsiCustomer(ref ErrorCode, ref Error);

                if (lstAMLRequestDetails.Count > 0)
                {                                        
                        string ThreadCount = "";
                        Common.GetParamvalue("InwardAMLMultiThreadingCountCust", ref ThreadCount);
                        int iThreadCount = 0;
                        try
                        {
                            iThreadCount = Convert.ToInt32(ThreadCount);
                        }
                        catch { iThreadCount = 3; }

                        ProcessQueue<AMLRequestDetails> queue = new ProcessQueue<AMLRequestDetails>(lstAMLRequestDetails, ProcessInwardAMLRequestSendProcess, iThreadCount);
                        queue.Start();
                        queue.Dispose();                                                       
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Common.WriteFTSLog("Exception occured during Inward AML Posting Process: " + ex.Message.ToString() + ex.StackTrace);
                Common.handleErrorLogInService(ex);
            }
        }
public string PutMessageOnQueue_Inward(string message, string strMessageID)
        {
            string writeQueueName = Common.WRITE_MESSAGE_QUEUENAME_INWARD;
            try
            {
                Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();

                properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
                properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, Common.FTS_MQ_HostName);
                properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, Common.QUEUE_CHANNEL);
                properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, Common.FTS_MQ_Port);
                properties.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, Common.FTS_MQ_UserId);
                properties.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, Common.FTS_MQ_Password);
                properties.Add(MQC.USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION_PROPERTY, true);

                using (var objMQQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(Common.QUEUEMANAGER_NAME, properties))
                {
                    using (var objMQQueue = objMQQueueManager.AccessQueue(writeQueueName, MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING))
                    {
                        var objPutMQMessage = new MQMessage
                        {
                            //UTF-8 character encoding 
                            CharacterSet = 1208,
                            Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING,
                            MessageType = MQC.MQMT_DATAGRAM,
                            Report = MQC.MQRO_NONE,                            
                        };

                        objPutMQMessage.WriteString(message);

                        objMQQueue.Put(objPutMQMessage);

                        objMQQueueManager.Commit();
                        objMQQueue.Close();
                        objMQQueueManager.Disconnect();                                            
                    }                    
                } 
            }
            catch (MQException mqEx)
            {
                message = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                message = null;
            }

            return message;
        }


There is nothing in the posted code that uses multiple threads. A good practice when using any library is to read the documentation to see what thread safety guarantees it have. If nothing is specified, then assume that any instance members are not thread safe.

Can you provide the details of the error(s) you are getting?

getting error code from MQ as compcode 2 reason 2009

You need to show what ProcessQueue is doing, as I suspect it is sharing resources across the threads allowing them to interfere with each other.

What piece of code calls method PutMessageOnQueue_Inward? Because I don't see it.
You cannot share an MQ connection and/or queue handles across threads. Each thread MUST have its own connection to the queue manager.
Since you didn't set MQPMO 'options' parameter to MQPMO_SYNCPOINT then this line of code is pointless:
objMQQueueManager.Commit();

You need to do a better job handling exceptions. You have 6 MQ API calls in your code, which MQ API call is throwing the MQ exception?
Also, you should be doing the close and disconnect methods calls in a finally statement.

"You cannot share an MQ connection and/or queue handles across threads. Each thread MUST have its own connection to the queue manager."
has not been true for many many releases. (Since V5 perhaps). If you're using the C client, then the MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE* options can be used. And in some environments - eg the Go language wrapper, or JMS - the option is automatically used so you don't need to specify anything.

@MarkTaylorwhat about .NET?

Default for the base .Net classes is shared hconn - so you can use it across threads. Though you could perhaps override it if you really wanted to (why?) And XMS would be the same as JMS

@MarkTaylor I always say that because it is too hard to explain MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE* options and that blocking will take place. So, if the 'hconn' handle can be used across threads by default with .NET, so you think he is simply messing up the 'hconn handle'? i.e. resetting it

@Mark Taylor Multithreading to MQ request is working without UserId and Password. If we send a request with UserId and password then we will get connection error for few items and few item will success
